# how to identify the user on subsequent requests to asp.net mvc web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, authentication, session-cookies, token

I am building an ASP.net MVC web application and I am starting to look into security.

What would be the best way to identify the user on subsequent requests (after they have logged in). I'm thinking of some form of authentication token or maybe using a cookie?

Ive read about Forms-Based Authentication but I'm not sure what would be a good approach?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad question and there are many ways to answer it. I would recommend that you learn the basics of identity and access in ASP.NET by reading each topic in the [ASP.NET Identity section](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started) and understanding what options you have. At a basic level, you need a mechanism to register users in a repository/database of some sort, validate their credentials when they log in, and a way to persist their user session in a browser (such as via a cookie). All of this is discussed in that section with examples.

The good news is that there are many valid authentication options that are pretty easy to implement and don't require you to be an expert on security. You can create/maintain your own member database, use Windows authentication, outsource authentication entirely to external identity providers such as Facebook/Google/Azure Active Directory/etc, and so on. The new tooling in Visual Studio 2013 also makes this much easier for you to manage. I would highly recommend you familiarize yourself with all of these options before jumping in and writing any code.